# Horror movie that takes place on a Nazi ship

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

This starts on a cruise liner whose captain (I think played by George Kennedy) for some reason was disillusioned with his lot in life. One night, something crashes into and sinks the liner; only the captain and a few passengers make it to a lifeboat.

Adrift in the ocean, the survivors come across a ship and board it, surprised to find no crew or passengers. If memory serves, they found a film or some paraphernalia that reveals that this ship was built in Germany during the Third Reich and numerous atrocities were committed onboard.

Various objects on the ship animate and attack the passengers, killing them one by one, while the captain starts to descend into megalomania, declaring himself the new captain of this ship.

This was too old to be *Ghost Ship* (2002).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is ***[Death Ship](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080603/)*** (1980).

> A mysterious ghostly freighter rams and sinks a modern day cruise ship whose survivors climb aboard the freighter and discover that it is a World War II Nazi torture vessel.

The film stars Richard Crenna as Trevor Marshall and George Kennedy as Captain Ashland. Ashland is the captain of a cruise ship travelling through the Atlantic Ocean, but he's unhappy, as he's scheduled to be retired and replaced in a few days by Marshall, who's also on the ship with his wife and two kids.

One night, the crew detect another unidentified ship on a collision course with theirs, and are unable to avoid a collision despite their best efforts. The cruise ship is sunk, with Marshall and his family, plus Ashland and a few others as the only survivors, adrift on a large piece of wreckage.

The next morning, they notice a decrepit-looking ship right next to them and manage to board it, but find no one else aboard. And somehow, the engines are still running, without any fuel. Suffice it to say, the ship seems to be haunted, and intent on picking them off, one by one. Also, Ashland is behaving oddly, as if he's under the ship's influence.

Marshall eventually discovers a room full of Nazi paraphernalia, and other rooms with large numbers of corpses in them and evidence of torture having been carried out. At one point, an old film projector which had originally been playing 1940s pop music starts showing footage of a Nazi parade.